# "public" not supported or disabled in libcurl error

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm learning how to create a custom JSON migration and referring to the *migrate_json_example* module, I see the following code in migrate_plus.migration.product.yml.

```
urls:
    - 'public://migrate_json_example/products.json'
  # An xpath-like selector corresponding to the items to be imported.
  item_selector: product
```

Can someone please tell me how to use that *public://* part of the URL?
I understand it's a path to the JSON file, but it's a relative path. I don't know how *public://* is handled and how Drupal knows where to look for the files.

Both modules are installed on the same site. However, when I try using the same *public://* URL in my module, I get the following error.

> Error message: cURL error 1: Protocol "public" not supported or disabled in libcurl (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) at public://migrate_stuff/resources/people1.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public://` is the sites public file system path. You can change it by navigation to `admin/config/media/file-system`.
    There you can set the public file system path, the default path is `sites/default/files`.

Comment: Thank you. I see my mistake now

Comment: For anyone else referring to this question, my mistake was I thought the migrate code was reading the json file located in the example module. However, in the module.install file, the json is copied into sites/default/files where it actually reads from - hence public:// makes complete sense.